# Deleting characters in a CSV column with sed

Tags: bash, csv, sed

I have a CSV file in with the following format:

```
aaxx1234a1,aaxx1234a1
aaxx1234a2,aaxx1234a2
```

Im trying to use sed to delete the 2 characters before the comma in the first field so as the file becomes:

```
aaxx1234,aaxx1234a1
aaxx1234,aaxx1234a2
```

I tried `sed 's/.{2},//'` but this didn't seem to do anything.

Can anyone give a pointer ?

Comment: if you are only matching two characters it would be easier to just do `s/..,/,/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sed needs the `{` to be backslashed to have the special meaning. Also, you don't want to remove the comma:

```
sed 's/.\{2\},/,/'
```

or, if your sed implementation supports it, switch to extended regexes by using `-r` or `-E`:

```
sed -E 's/.{2},/,/'
```

Comment: Thanks... -E .. Just what I needed.

Comment: I think you may have to be more explicit i.e. what would happen if the **first** field were less than two characters long? Remember `.` matches a `,` too.

Answer (score 1):

For this regex syntax, you need extended Regex (`-r`) :

```
sed -r 's/.{2},/,/' test.csv
```